# how to align rows after manually forcing a line break in a tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am creating a big table where I manually break lines in the first column to be able to fit my table into the page. However, I face a minor problem. The following columns are aligned based on the bottom line.

I am sharing a small example. My goal is to make sure that the texts are aligned from the top rather than the bottom line.

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}
\toprule
\textbf{} & \textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B} \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{First} \\\textbf{Second} & Some text here & Some text there \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{My table}
\label{Table3}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you change the column type of the left-hand column from `l` to `p` and set the column's width to the longest word ("Second") that will occur in that column. Then, use `\newline` to induce a line break between "First" and "Second". Oh, and if all contents of the left-hand column are supposed to be **bold**, I'd automate that step as well, by prefixing `>{\bfseries}` to `p{\widthof{\textbf{Second}}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc} % for '\widthof' macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
     >{\bfseries}p{\widthof{\textbf{Second}}} 
     X 
     X 
     @{}}
\toprule
   & \textbf{Column A} & \textbf{Column B} \\ 
\midrule
First \newline Second & Some text here & Some text there \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{My table}
\label{Table3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- You insert content od cells in the last two columns into in the second row.
- What you after is simple achieve with use of the `tblr` table defined in the tabularray package.
- Using 7tblr` table, its code is more concise and simple (with comparison with your code fragment)
- MWE, which show to possible solution:

  - text in other is at top of cells
  - text in other cells is vertically centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l, font=\bfseries] *{2}{X[l]}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
                & Column A      & Column B          \\
    \midrule
{First\\    
    Second}     & Some text here & Some text there  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{My table}
\label{Table3}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l, m, font=\bfseries] *{2}{X[l]}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
                & Column A      & Column B          \\
    \midrule
{First\\
    Second}     & Some text here & Some text there  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{My table}
\label{Table3}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
As response to your comment:

- Proposed solution works also in cases when table has more `X` columns
- MWE below is tested by use of the recent version of the `tabularray` package (version 2023A, from 2023-03-01)
  . From received result, also shown below, follows, that your claims not hold. Proposed solutions works, as are provided, works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l, font=\bfseries] *{4}{X[l]}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
                & Column A  & Column B  & Column C  &   Column D    \\
    \midrule
{First\\
    Second}     & Some text & Some text & Some text & Some text     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{My table}
\label{Table3}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using your example for my big table containing four columns as ````\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l, font=\bfseries] *{4}{X[l]}},row{1} = {font=\bfseries}}````. However, it does not align.

Comment: @whitepanda, it works (as the first example in my answer). Tested. Please edit you question and extend your code fragment to more realistic example (with at least two rows). Which version of `tabularray` you use?